# divisors Exercise from practice python

Tags: python

I created a code to answer this question :

Create a program that asks the user for a number and then prints out a list of all the divisors of that number. (If you don’t know what a divisor is, it is a number that divides evenly into another number. For example, 13 is a divisor of 26 because 26 / 13 has no remainder.)

unfortunately, my program doesn't return the divisor values for a given number. Here is my code :

```
print('Enter a number to know its divisors :')
number = int(input())

while number > 1:
    inf = number - 1
    result = number % inf
    if result == 0:
        print (inf)
```

Could you please tell me where is my error ? I would also like your comments on how to make this program more simple if possible.

Best

Comment: you're not decreasing `number` or `inf`: you get an infinite loop.

Comment: use a for-loop.

Comment: Merci @Jean-François. What if I add `number = number - 1` at the end ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually decrement the variable `inf` in your for-loop, and run the loop until `inf` reaches 1 (as opposed to `number`, which should be kept the same). However, you can write the program much more easily using `range`, `filter`, and a `lambda` function:

```
print('Enter a number to know its divisors :')
number = int(input())

for divisor in filter(lambda x: number % x == 0, range(1, number)):
    print(divisor)
```

**Edit:** I feel like a bit of an idiot for forgetting that you can use `for ... in ... if` to filter instead.

```
print([x for x in range(1, number) if number % x == 0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gyre. I didn't know filter and lambda functions. I tried to search on the web but I didn't really understand. Maybe could you explain me your code (and how this 2 functions act) ? Otherwise, thanks a lot it is working perfectly

Comment: Sure. `range(1, number)` gives you a a sequence of numbers from 1 to `number`, which form all possible divisors, then you `filter` all of those possibilities to produce a sequence with only those numbers `x` for which `number % x == 0` (in other words, those which can evenly divide `number`). The `for ... in` statement just iterates over all of the divisors found and prints them.

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution:

```
num=int(input("enter a number"))
lst=[]
for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i==0:
        lst.append(i)
print(lst)
```